# Take parts of a string and create separate variables in bash

Tags: arrays, string, bash, variables, wget

I would like to take this string:

```
t.mysite\/images\/test\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/001.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/002.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/003.thumb.jpg"];
```

separate it so I have:

```
var1 = "t.mysite/images/test/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/images/001.jpg"
var2 = "t.mysite/images/test/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/images/002.jpg"
var3 = "t.mysite/images/test/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/images/003.jpg"
```

and then wget each of the variables.

If possible to add the taken files into another directory say /home/mike/Pictures.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: about the format for your original string, is it some recognized format, like a python array or something?

Comment: I mean, is there any chance that there will be the sequence `","` _inside_ some URL?

Comment: It looks almost like JSON, but it's missing the `["` at the beginning. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: the URL will have no "," in it

Comment: If it's actually JSON, take a look at [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Comment: It is not JSON its for a simple script im writing for linux to make my life easier that will run for the terminal. Like I said im new to this :) @Barmar

Comment: Why do all the filenames have `"` at the beginning and end, except for the first one?

Comment: Also, the forward-slashes (`/`) are escaped. It really looks like it's from a formal language (and indeed looks like JSON, but could be python)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Using **parameter expansion with substring extraction** along with **substring replacement** is an easy way to parse the strings into separate variables. The following keys off of the `","//` separators between the strings. As such as long as you provide like formatted lines, the following will separate the original into 3 vars as requested:

```
#!/bin/bash

str='t.mysite\/images\/test\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/001.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/002.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/003.thumb.jpg"];'

var1=${str%%\"*}         # remove from rt. to first " (substring extraction)
var1=${var1//\\/}        # remove all \               (substring replacement)

var2=${str//\\/}         # remove all \                      (ss replacement)
var2=${var2#*\",\"\/\/}  # remove up to first ","// from lt. (ss extraction)
var2=${var2%%\"*}        # remove all to first " from rt.    (ss extraction)

var3=${str//\\/}         # remove all \                     (ss replacement)
var3=${var3##*\",\"\/\/} # remove up to last ","// from rt. (ss extraction)
var3=${var3%%\"*}        # remove all to first " from rt.   (ss extraction)

echo "var1: $var1"       # output variables
echo "var2: $var2"
echo "var3: $var3"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
$  bash parsestr.sh
var1: t.mysite/images/test/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/thumbs/001.thumb.jpg
var2: t.mysite/images/manga/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/thumbs/002.thumb.jpg
var3: t.mysite/images/manga/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/thumbs/003.thumb.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you that looks like it is close to what I am looking for, however It needs to be automated. The string could be longer or shorter the user (me) will not always know what the str is. Eg I gave you only 3 urls in that string, but it could be up to 26 or even 100 and remove the .thumb parts (so some sort of loop i'm guessing)

Then a simple wget for each of the created variables.

Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBullock : StackOverflow isn't a free coding service. David has given you an excellent set of tools here, you'll have to make an attempt to use them. OR  your requirement to process 100+ URLS in one command is new and way-out-of-scope. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following script: (don't trust the syntax highlighting here; the quote `"` in the command inside `"$(command)"` does *not* break the outer quote)

```
string='["sd\"fg","dgf","dsfgsdfg\\sdfg"];'
echo "\$string is $string"

#strip off the initial [" and ending "];
string="$(echo $string | sed -r 's:^\s?\[?\s?"?::' | sed -r 's:"?\s?\]?\s?;?\s?$::')"
echo "\$string is $string"

echo
while [[ $string ]]; do
    url=$(echo $string |
          sed -r 's:^((\\"|\\\\|\\/|[^"])*).*:\1:' | # take just the first url
          sed -r 's:\\":":g' | sed -r 's:\\/:/:g' | sed -r 's:\\\\:\\:g' # clean it from any \"
         )
    echo "url is \"$url\""
    # do what you want with $url

    # remove the first url from the string
    string="$(echo $string | sed -r 's:^((\\"|\\\\|[^"])*)::' | sed -r 's:^","::')"
done
```

In my system, the output is:

```
$string is ["sd\"fg","dgf","dsfgsdfg\\sdfg"];
$string is sd\"fg","dgf","dsfgsdfg\\sdfg

url is "sd"fg"
url is "dgf"
url is "dsfgsdfg\sdfg"
```

With your input, the output is:

```
$string is t.mysite\/images\/test\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/001.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/002.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/003.thumb.jpg"];
$string is t.mysite\/images\/test\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/001.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/002.thumb.jpg","\/\/t.mysite\/images\/manga\/m\/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer\/thumbs\/003.thumb.jpg

url is "t.mysite/images/test/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/thumbs/001.thumb.jpg"
url is "//t.mysite/images/manga/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/thumbs/002.thumb.jpg"
url is "//t.mysite/images/manga/m/[mike]_Original_Work_-_summer/thumbs/003.thumb.jpg"
```

The output you want is different though. Do you really want to remove the `.thumb` part?